# SOAPUI : Need Sample REST APIs to test using SOAPUI Tool

Tags: rest, soapui

Hi Can anyone let me know where I can find sample RESTFul APIs so that I can have hands on experience working on them using GET/POST/DELETE methods.

Thanks.

Comment: The soapUI installer comes with an option to install some sample/tutorial projects. These are a good place to start. If you don't have them, run the installer again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an idea about Java, Servlet, Wildfly / Tomcat server, Mysql then you can create a basic program for Get / Post Method and deploy on the local server.

You will learn to create basic API also. The best way you install eclipse and integrate server. With Eclipse, you can easily create Servlet as it provides template and web.xml generate automatically.

Create a basic object Class. Call it in servelet fill some data. 
Convert it to JSON by using GSON

```
@WebServlet(asyncSupported = true, urlPatterns = { "/School_getEmployee" })
public class School_Employee_servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
String json = gson.toJson(Object);
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(json);
}
```

Now you can use this servlet as API for testing.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. I have idea on java and Tomcat server but no idea about servlet. So, i thought of checking if any available APIs will be available for testing.

Comment: Okay, there are free limited API available from Google, facebook, yahoo like places, maps, Graph API. You may use for normal testing but not for load testing.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks/
https://developers.google.com/products/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON-SERVER](https://github.com/typicode/json-server), I'm using these to make GET/PUT/POST/DELETE

[image]